# Update multiple rows - errors in generated SQL?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, sql-update

I am trying to update multiple `pages` rows of my database to update the ordering of the menu.

`pages` has 2 database fields that need to be updated: `parent_page_id` and `menu_ordering`.
The id of the database table is `page_id`. All fields are integers.

The SQL I created is as following:

```
UPDATE `pages` SET parent_page_id = CASE page_id WHEN 256 THEN 0 WHEN 259 THEN 256 WHEN 239 THEN 256 WHEN 242 THEN 0 WHEN 246 THEN 0 WHEN 254 THEN 0 WHEN 255 THEN 0 END, SET menu_ordering = CASE page_id WHEN 256 THEN 0 WHEN 259 THEN 0 WHEN 239 THEN 1 WHEN 242 THEN 0 WHEN 246 THEN 0 WHEN 254 THEN 0 WHEN 255 THEN 0 END WHERE page_id IN (256, 259, 239, 242, 246, 254, 255);
```

Human readable:

```
UPDATE `pages` 
SET parent_page_id = CASE page_id 
    WHEN 256 THEN 0 
    WHEN 259 THEN 256 
    WHEN 239 THEN 256 
    WHEN 242 THEN 0 
    WHEN 246 THEN 0 
    WHEN 254 THEN 0 
    WHEN 255 THEN 0 
END, 
SET menu_ordering = CASE page_id 
    WHEN 256 THEN 0 
    WHEN 259 THEN 0 
    WHEN 239 THEN 1 
    WHEN 242 THEN 0 
    WHEN 246 THEN 0 
    WHEN 254 THEN 0 
    WHEN 255 THEN 0 
END 
WHERE page_id IN (256, 259, 239, 242, 246, 254, 255);
```

Sadly, this SQL contains errors. I just can't figure out why?
I've used this 'guide' to get this SQL http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/
and my syntax seems to be exactly the same?

Can you help me find the error(s)?

Comment: use only one time SET: ....... END, 
menu_ordering = CASE page_id

Comment: What's the error message and why is `pages` in backticks? Just a formatting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the second `SET`

```
UPDATE `pages` 
SET parent_page_id = CASE page_id 
    WHEN 256 THEN 0 
    WHEN 259 THEN 256 
    WHEN 239 THEN 256 
    WHEN 242 THEN 0 
    WHEN 246 THEN 0 
    WHEN 254 THEN 0 
    WHEN 255 THEN 0 
END, 
menu_ordering = CASE page_id 
    WHEN 256 THEN 0 
    WHEN 259 THEN 0 
    WHEN 239 THEN 1 
    WHEN 242 THEN 0 
    WHEN 246 THEN 0 
    WHEN 254 THEN 0 
    WHEN 255 THEN 0 
END 
WHERE page_id IN (256, 259, 239, 242, 246, 254, 255);
```

Answer (score 1):

only one set

```
 UPDATE `pages` 
 SET parent_page_id = CASE page_id 
   WHEN 256 THEN 0 
   WHEN 259 THEN 256 
   WHEN 239 THEN 256 
   WHEN 242 THEN 0 
   WHEN 246 THEN 0 
   WHEN 254 THEN 0 
   WHEN 255 THEN 0 
END, 
menu_ordering = CASE page_id 
  WHEN 256 THEN 0 
  WHEN 259 THEN 0 
  WHEN 239 THEN 1 
  WHEN 242 THEN 0 
  WHEN 246 THEN 0 
  WHEN 254 THEN 0 
  WHEN 255 THEN 0 
END 
WHERE page_id IN (256, 259, 239, 242, 246, 254, 255);
```